# Why is $\mathbb E(X) =\mathbb E(Y)$ in this joint probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

If we know $X|Y$ is a normal random variable with mean $Y$ and variance $2$, and $Y$ is a binomial distribution with success probability $0.3$ and the number of trials $5$, why is $\mathbb E(Y) = 0.3\times5 =\mathbb E(X)?$

Comment: since $E(X)=EE(X|Y)$ so $E(X)=EE(X|Y)=E(Y)$

Answer (score 0):

$E(X|Y)=Y$ so (by taking expectation on both sides) we get $EX=EY$. Since $Y\sim B(0,3.5)$ we have  $EY=(0.3)(5)$.

Comment: if these information, can we find out what is var(x)?

Comment: Yes, Use the following: $E(X^{2}|Y)=2+Y^{2}$ and $EX^{2}=2+EY^{2}$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\V}{\operatorname{Var}}$To find $\V(X)$, you can try using [the fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) that $\V(X) = \Bbb{E}[\V(X\mid Y)]+ \V(\Bbb{E}[X\mid Y])$.